# First-chance exception cudaError_enum at memory location

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cuda

I'm getting this error when running my app from Visual Studio 2012.
Development Specs:

- Cuda 5.0
- VS C++ 2012
- Quadro K4000

I've seen there are other posts related [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952742/unable-to-find-source-of-exception-cudaerror-enum-at-memory-location), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221083/exception-first-chance-cudaerror-enum-at-memory) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635093/exception-cudaerror-enum-thrown-in-cudagetexporttable-cuda-runtime-library) but none has a good answer to my problem. I'm checking all the return codes from CUDA API, CuRAND and CuBLAS and all are returning SUCCESS. I looked in the code where was the problem raising and it happens to be when I create a timer object for the GPU.

I'm using the timer that comes with CUDA SDK

```
struct GpuTimer{
    cudaEvent_t start;
    cudaEvent_t stop;
    GpuTimer(){
        checkCudaErr(
            cudaEventCreate(&start)
            );

        checkCudaErr(
            cudaEventCreate(&stop)
            );
    }
    ~GpuTimer(){
        checkCudaErr(
            cudaEventDestroy(start)
            );
        checkCudaErr(
            cudaEventDestroy(stop)
            );
    }
    void Start(){
        checkCudaErr(
            cudaEventRecord(start, 0)
            );
    }
    void Stop(){
        checkCudaErr(
            cudaEventRecord(stop, 0)
            );
    }
    float Elapsed(){
        float elapsed;
        checkCudaErr(
            cudaEventSynchronize(stop)
            );

        checkCudaErr(
            cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsed, start, stop)
            );
        return elapsed;
    }
};
```

so in the main function I have

```
int main(args)
{
   ...
   ...
   ...
   GpuTimer t;
   ...
   ...
}
```

and exactly after that line is executed I get

```
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nvcuda.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\lpk.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\usp10.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\setupapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\devobj.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll'
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nvapi64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wintrust.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msasn1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFDA29E5D in App.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cudaError_enum at memory location 0x000000000018EA00. //Repeated 20 times at least
```

finally, just after launching the application I saw this messages in the output console (on VS2012)

```
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\bin\cudart64_50_35.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\bin\cublas64_50_35.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'App.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\bin\curand64_50_35.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
```

The application runs just fine and results look fine to me but I would like to know what could be causing this errors/exceptions and how to solve them, or if I should just ignore them.

Comment: The "Cannot find or the PDB file" errors are superfluous, that just means you app wants to drop into the debugger but the system libraries don't have symbol files. Can you show code where you actually use the timer class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The observation you are making has to do with an exception that is caught and handled properly within the CUDA libraries.  It is, in some cases, a normal part of CUDA GPU operation.  As you have observed, your application returns no API errors and runs correctly.  If you were not within the VS environment that can report this, you would not observe this at all.

This is considered normal behavior under CUDA 5.0.  I believe there were some attempts to eliminate it in CUDA 5.5.  You might wish to try that, although it's not considered an issue either way.

You might also be interested in [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564681/what-is-a-first-chance-exception).

Comment: Surprisingly I commented out that line of code (and everything realted to timings) and what I found was that it is the first CUDA call that launches all those exceptions. Is there some documentation on this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any documentation on it.

Comment: I have experience the same using CUDA cuda blast