# Exception error in CUDA/GPU on calling function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cuda, gpu

Hi I am having an exception error in CUDA.. I am trying to run the following code as it is..

```
CUdeviceptr  pDecodedFrame[2] = { 0, 0 };
CUdeviceptr  pInteropFrame[2] = { 0, 0 };

uint32 n_Width  = g_pVideoDecoder->targetWidth();
uint32 n_Height = g_pVideoDecoder->targetHeight();

dim3 block(32,16,1);
dim3 grid((nWidth+(2*block.x-1))/(2*block.x), (nHeight+(block.y-1))/block.y, 1);

NV12ToARGB_drvapi<<<block,grid>>>(&pDecodedFrame[active_field], nDecodedPitch,
 &pInteropFrame[active_field], nTexturePitch, nWidth, nHeight,constHueColorSpaceMat, constAlpha);
```

My other function is as follows :

```
__global__ void NV12ToARGB_drvapi(uint32 *srcImage,     size_t nSourcePitch,
                              uint32 *dstImage,     size_t nDestPitch,
                              uint32 width,         uint32 height,  float  constHueColorSpaceMat[9] , uint32 constAlpha)
{
    int32 x, y;
    uint32 yuv101010Pel[2];
    uint32 processingPitch = ((width) + 63) & ~63;
    uint32 dstImagePitch   = nDestPitch >> 2;
    uint8 *srcImageU8     = (uint8 *)srcImage;

processingPitch = nSourcePitch;

// Pad borders with duplicate pixels, and we multiply by 2 because we process 2 pixels per thread
x = blockIdx.x * (blockDim.x << 1) + (threadIdx.x << 1);
y = blockIdx.y *  blockDim.y       +  threadIdx.y;

if (x >= width)
    return; //x = width - 1;

if (y >= height)
    return; // y = height - 1;

// Read 2 Luma components at a time, so we don't waste processing since CbCr are decimated this way.
// if we move to texture we could read 4 luminance values
yuv101010Pel[0] = (srcImageU8[y * processingPitch + x    ]) << 2;
yuv101010Pel[1] = (srcImageU8[y * processingPitch + x + 1]) << 2;

uint32 chromaOffset    = processingPitch * height;
int32 y_chroma = y >> 1;

if (y & 1)  // odd scanline ?
{
    uint32 chromaCb;
    uint32 chromaCr;

    chromaCb = srcImageU8[chromaOffset + y_chroma * processingPitch + x    ];
    chromaCr = srcImageU8[chromaOffset + y_chroma * processingPitch + x + 1];

    if (y_chroma < ((height >> 1) - 1)) // interpolate chroma vertically
    {
        chromaCb = (chromaCb + srcImageU8[chromaOffset + (y_chroma + 1) * processingPitch + x    ] + 1) >> 1;
        chromaCr = (chromaCr + srcImageU8[chromaOffset + (y_chroma + 1) * processingPitch + x + 1] + 1) >> 1;
    }

    yuv101010Pel[0] |= (chromaCb << (COLOR_COMPONENT_BIT_SIZE       + 2));
    yuv101010Pel[0] |= (chromaCr << ((COLOR_COMPONENT_BIT_SIZE << 1) + 2));

    yuv101010Pel[1] |= (chromaCb << (COLOR_COMPONENT_BIT_SIZE       + 2));
    yuv101010Pel[1] |= (chromaCr << ((COLOR_COMPONENT_BIT_SIZE << 1) + 2));
}
else
{
    yuv101010Pel[0] |= ((uint32)srcImageU8[chromaOffset + y_chroma * processingPitch + x    ] << (COLOR_COMPONENT_BIT_SIZE       + 2));
    yuv101010Pel[0] |= ((uint32)srcImageU8[chromaOffset + y_chroma * processingPitch + x + 1] << ((COLOR_COMPONENT_BIT_SIZE << 1) + 2));

    yuv101010Pel[1] |= ((uint32)srcImageU8[chromaOffset + y_chroma * processingPitch + x    ] << (COLOR_COMPONENT_BIT_SIZE       + 2));
    yuv101010Pel[1] |= ((uint32)srcImageU8[chromaOffset + y_chroma * processingPitch + x + 1] << ((COLOR_COMPONENT_BIT_SIZE << 1) + 2));
}

// this steps performs the color conversion
uint32 yuvi[6];
float red[2], green[2], blue[2];

yuvi[0] = (yuv101010Pel[0] &   COLOR_COMPONENT_MASK);
yuvi[1] = ((yuv101010Pel[0] >>  COLOR_COMPONENT_BIT_SIZE)       & COLOR_COMPONENT_MASK);
yuvi[2] = ((yuv101010Pel[0] >> (COLOR_COMPONENT_BIT_SIZE << 1)) & COLOR_COMPONENT_MASK);

yuvi[3] = (yuv101010Pel[1] &   COLOR_COMPONENT_MASK);
yuvi[4] = ((yuv101010Pel[1] >>  COLOR_COMPONENT_BIT_SIZE)       & COLOR_COMPONENT_MASK);
yuvi[5] = ((yuv101010Pel[1] >> (COLOR_COMPONENT_BIT_SIZE << 1)) & COLOR_COMPONENT_MASK);

// YUV to RGB Transformation conversion
YUV2RGB(&yuvi[0], &red[0], &green[0], &blue[0], constHueColorSpaceMat);
YUV2RGB(&yuvi[3], &red[1], &green[1], &blue[1], constHueColorSpaceMat);

// Clamp the results to RGBA
dstImage[y * dstImagePitch + x     ] = RGBAPACK_10bit(red[0], green[0], blue[0], constAlpha);
dstImage[y * dstImagePitch + x + 1 ] = RGBAPACK_10bit(red[1], green[1], blue[1], constAlpha);

}






    __device__ void YUV2RGB(uint32 *yuvi, float *red, float *green, float *blue,  float  constHueColorSpaceMat[9])

{
    float luma, chromaCb, chromaCr;

// Prepare for hue adjustment
luma     = (float)yuvi[0];
chromaCb = (float)((int32)yuvi[1] - 512.0f);
chromaCr = (float)((int32)yuvi[2] - 512.0f);

// Convert YUV To RGB with hue adjustment
*red  = MUL(luma,     constHueColorSpaceMat[0]) +
        MUL(chromaCb, constHueColorSpaceMat[1]) +
        MUL(chromaCr, constHueColorSpaceMat[2]);
*green= MUL(luma,     constHueColorSpaceMat[3]) +
        MUL(chromaCb, constHueColorSpaceMat[4]) +
        MUL(chromaCr, constHueColorSpaceMat[5]);
*blue = MUL(luma,     constHueColorSpaceMat[6]) +
        MUL(chromaCb, constHueColorSpaceMat[7]) +
        MUL(chromaCr, constHueColorSpaceMat[8]);
}


__device__ uint32 RGBAPACK_8bit(float red, float green, float blue, uint32 alpha)
{
    uint32 ARGBpixel = 0;

// Clamp final 10 bit results
red   = min(max(red,   0.0f), 255.0f);
green = min(max(green, 0.0f), 255.0f);
blue  = min(max(blue,  0.0f), 255.0f);

// Convert to 8 bit unsigned integers per color component
ARGBpixel = (((uint32)blue) |
             (((uint32)green) << 8)  |
             (((uint32)red) << 16) | (uint32)alpha);

return  ARGBpixel;
}
```

This is the error I am having

```
    First-chance exception at 0x7571812f in testing_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cudaError at memory location 0x0015e6b8..
First-chance exception at 0x7571812f in testing_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000..
```

Everytime I am running the GPU code. Anybody can help me out here please.

Comment: There have been posted many questions asking about first-chance exception in CUDA. See for example [First-chance exception cudaError_enum at memory location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126098/first-chance-exception-cudaerror-enum-at-memory-location). Robert Crovella has exhaustively answered such a kind of questions many times, including the one I have linked. In this sense, your question seems to be a duplicate and perhaps could have been found by a simple google search. I'm not sure if SO has some space for frequently asked questions. It would be very useful in these cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is running normally and returning no errors (are you doing [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api)?) the first chance exception will be seen only when running in the MSVC environment and can safely be ignored.

Some of the CUDA libraries run into exceptions during ordinary processing functions.  These exceptions are handled normally, but when you are in the MSVC environment, Visual Studio gives you the option of intercepting the exception and having "first chance" access to it, before it is passed to the ordinary exception handler built into the code/library.

You should not see this if you are running your application from the command line, outside of the MSVC environment.

You may also see a difference in behavior if you switch to CUDA 5.5

Comment: hm thank you.. I am trying to run it and my libraries are right the problem is if i run the same code through a different file i am not having any exception but in this case i cannot even save the output file. Its a null file.

Comment: Are you doing cuda error checking?  Probably you should provide a full repro case rather than this snippet of code.